# node package which support function serialization?

Tags: node.js, serialization, read-eval-print-loop

I am looking for a serialization library for node.js

JS object is natively serializable by JSON, except functions. Anyway I need also serialization of functions too. This is not to interchange data. I just want to store my program wrote in node REPL as an image form. (you can imagine Smalltalk image)

So what I need is very robust function serialization implementation. Functions should be stored in source code form.

What kind of package can I use for this purpose? Or should I roll one myself?

Comment: Functions are not the only thing unsupported by JSON, so are dates, regexps and other built-in objects, prototype chain, circular references and closures. So you better go on your own implementing only the parts you really need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `toString` on the function will give you valid source code for the function. It may not be the original source code (comments removed for example). You can't solve the problem of closure state being lost, so your function cannot reference any variables it doesn't define itself or are defined as arguments. You can recreate the function using `new Function(str)`